# Validate format of dynamic segment in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a preferred way of checking the format of a dynamic segment param in ember.js? For example, say I have the URL `/date/:date` and want to ensure that `:date` is a ISO-8601 formatted date (YYYY-MM-DD).

You *could* do it in the Route's `model` hook, and reject the promise if your validation fails. Perhaps that is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that the [beforeModel](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel) hook is the best place to do that. You can read more about it [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_beforemodel-and-aftermodel). I believe they added that hook for reasons very similar to yours; to see whether it should even attempt to resolve the model.

Comment: That makes sense. However, beforeModel receives `transition` and `queryParams` as its arguments. To access (and validate) `params` you need to look in `transition.params['route-name']['param-name']`--you don't have direct access to the parameters relevant to your route which I found strange.